# I want sidebar toggle can't close and position of overflow can't change when page reload

Tags: html, jquery, css, .net, model-view-controller

```html
<div class="side-bar" id="sidebar">
    <img style="width:150px; height: 100px; margin-left:20px;" src="~/Images/background3.png" />
    <div class="border-top my-1"></div>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item">
            <a class="sub-btn" id="home" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fas fa-cogs"></i>Settings<i class="fas fa-angle-right dropdown"></i></a>
            <div class="sub-menu" id="home-collapse">
                <a class="sub-item" href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'>Depreciation Methods</a>
                <div class="border-top my-1"></div>
                <a class="sub-item" href='@Url.Action("Classes", "Home")'>Classes</a>
                <div class="border-top my-1"></div>
                <a class="sub-item" href='@Url.Action("CompanyInfo", "Home")'>Company Info</a>
                <div class="border-top my-1"></div>
                <a class="sub-item" href='@Url.Action("Categories", "Home")'>Categories</a>
                <div class="border-top my-1"></div>
                <a class="sub-item" href='@Url.Action("TaxCategories", "Home")'>Tax Categories</a>
                <div class="border-top my-1"></div>
                <a class="sub-item" href='@Url.Action("BaseValueDepreMethod", "Home")'>Base Value For Depr. Mtds</a>
                <div class="border-top my-1"></div>
                <a class="sub-item" href='@Url.Action("PeriodControl", "Home")'>Period Control</a>
                <div class="border-top my-1"></div>
                <a class="sub-item" href='@Url.Action("DepreciationAria", "Home")'>Define Depreciation Area</a>
                <div class="border-top my-1"></div>
                <a class="sub-item" href='@Url.Action("NameForPeriodControl", "Home")'>Names For the Period Control</a>
                <div class="border-top my-1"></div>
                <a class="sub-item" href='@Url.Action("UnitOfNewAsset", "Home")'>Unit Of New Assets</a>
                <div class="border-top my-1"></div>
                <a class="sub-item" href='@Url.Action("Components", "Home")'>Components</a>
                <div class="border-top my-1"></div>
                <a class="sub-item" href='@Url.Action("Suppliers", "Home")'>Suppliers</a>
                <div class="border-top my-1"></div>
                <a class="sub-item" href='@Url.Action("Makers", "Home")'>Makers</a>
                <div class="border-top my-1"></div>
                <a class="sub-item" href='@Url.Action("Financial_Period", "Home")'>Financial Period</a>
                <div class="border-top my-1"></div>
                <a class="sub-item" href='@Url.Action("MandatoryInfo", "Home")'>Mandatory Info</a>
                <div class="border-top my-1"></div>
              
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a class="sub-btn" id="assets"><i class="fas fa-th-list"></i>Assets<i class="fas fa-angle-right dropdown"></i></a>
            <div class="sub-menu" id="Assets-collapse">
                <a class="sub-item" href='@Url.Action("CreateAssets", "Home")'>New Asset</a>
                <div class="border-top my-1"></div>
                <a class="sub-item" href='@Url.Action("ExistingAssets", "Home")'>Existing Assets</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container body-content"  style="margin-left: 250px;">
    @RenderBody()

    @*        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>*@
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.sub-btn').click(function () {
            $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
            $(this).find('.dropdown').toggleClass('rotate');
        });
        $('#home').click(function () {
            $('#Assets-collapse').hide();
            $('#home-collapse').show();
        });
        $('#assets').click(function () {
            $('#Assets-collapse').show();
            $('#home-collapse').hide();
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var settingsCollapseState = localStorage.getItem('settingsCollapseState');
        if (settingsCollapseState === 'show') {
            $('#home-collapse, #Assets-collapse').addClass('show');
        }

        $('#home-collapse, #Assets-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
            localStorage.setItem('settingsCollapseState', 'show');
        });

        $('#home-collapse, #Assets-collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
            localStorage.removeItem('settingsCollapseState');
        });
    });
</script>
```

i want sidebar sub menu can't hide or close when page reload and position of sidebar scroll can't change when page reload, it still open

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the state of the sidebar in `localStorage` which will persist across page reloads. Just save it as a local variable instead.

You also have two `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` calls, you can just put all of your code in a single call to this.

Your JavaScript can be changed and simplified like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sub-btn').click(function () {
        $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
        $(this).find('.dropdown').toggleClass('rotate');
    });
    $('#home').click(function () {
        $('#Assets-collapse').hide();
        $('#home-collapse').show();
    });
    $('#assets').click(function () {
        $('#Assets-collapse').show();
        $('#home-collapse').hide();
    });

    var settingsCollapseState = true;

    $('#home-collapse, #Assets-collapse')
      .on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
          settingsCollapseState = false;
      })
      .on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
          settingsCollapseState = true;
      });
});
```

---

If I were to make further improvement here:

- it's a good idea to only call a jQuery element selector once and save them as variables
- All variable declarations should be at the top
- `$(function(){...})` is exactly the same as `$(document).ready(function() {...})` but shorter

The below code makes these changes and should function exactly the same.

```js
$(function () {
    var settingsCollapseState = true;
    var $collapseAssets = $('#Assets-collapse');
    var $collapseHome = $('#home-collapse');

    $('.sub-btn').click(function () {
        $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
        $(this).find('.dropdown').toggleClass('rotate');
    });

    $('#home').click(function () {
        $collapseAssets.hide();
        $collapseHome.show();
    });

    $('#assets').click(function () {
        $collapseAssets.show();
        $collapseHome.hide();
    });

    $collapseHome.add($collapseAssets)
      .on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
          settingsCollapseState = false;
      })
      .on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
          settingsCollapseState = true;
      });
});
```